# Image src sort on an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

This is a simulation. How do i store this image into an array and sort in terms of most recent and most like.

Do i need to set up an id. Any help is appreciated.

```
</style>

<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
    <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=1" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
    <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>

</figure>
<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=2" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
    <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=3" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
    <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=3" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
    <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=3" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
    <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>     
</figure>
```

Comment: Where does the date (_most recent_) and preference (_most likes_) info comes from?

Comment: it is just a simulation, it could be anything.